# CEP: source for real-time events or data feeds?

Tags: java, events, stream, esper, complex-event-processing

I am searching for free event sources that I can use within my java-application.
I am looking for something similar to [YahooFinance](http://finance.yahoo.com), where one can query a bunch of stock info and retrieve the result as csv.

Ideally, an API or a URL with some query string would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [SuperFeedr](http://superfeedr.com/)?

You could also run some SPARQL-query on some [SPARQL](http://de.dbpedia.org/)-Endpoint and "feed" the result back to your application. Here is a [list](http://www.w3.org/wiki/SparqlEndpoints) of some endpoints ([here](http://labs.mondeca.com/sparqlEndpointsStatus/index.html) including uptime and availability stats).

Twitter also offers an [Streaming-API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/site-streams), where one can listen for status changes etc.

Another way could be to implement some HTML-crawler that extracts interesting facts from webpages, but that's probably not what you are looking for...

**Kind of related:**

[Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) - observe activities on flickr
[SO - Cricket API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245174/live-cricket-scores-api-of-rss-feed)

Answer (score 1):

for this you can use **Rss4j** api which provide both read feed and also create you own feed.

hope this will help you

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't recommend exactely this library. I'd suggest you give Rome a try. It is available here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/rome/rome